# Not import module with Vue.js if using Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, vue.js, ckeditor

When I build my Vue.js application with vue-cli-service-build, I get a blank page with Internet Explorer (but it works with Firefox and Chrome).
I know the problme is related to CKEditor, since it is not supported by IE. 
However, I created a condition that only "requires" CKEditor if we're not using IE. This solution works with vue-cli-service-serve, but not vue-cli-service-build.

```
if(!usingIE())
{
alert("not using ieee");
CKEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue').component;
ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');


}
else
{
alert("using IE");
}
```

If I comment the two lines that "requires" CKEditor modules and build the app, it works with IE.

If I put false inside the condition but do not comment the two lines, it works with IE too. However, that's not what I want, because I need to allow users to use CKEditor if they're using Chrome/Firefox.

```
if(false)
{
alert("not using ieee");
CKEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue').component;
ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');
}
```

I want to know if I'm using the proper way to include modules that are not supported by a browser. Otherwise, what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **v-if** and **v-else** block to conditionally render the component.

Example:

```
<div v-if="type === 'A'">
  A
</div>
<div v-else-if="type === 'B'">
  B
</div>
<div v-else-if="type === 'C'">
  C
</div>
<div v-else>
  Not A/B/C
</div>
```

References:

(1) [Conditional Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

(2) [Conditional component rendering](https://spectrum.chat/vue-js/general/conditional-component-rendering%7Eaeb1a579-b547-4c5c-b887-04af9414525f)

(3) [Vue.js router - conditional component rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789991/vue-js-router-conditional-component-rendering)